# "JqGrid is not a function" AFTER the grid is loaded and working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

First... here is what I am using.
JQuery 1.4.4
JQuery-UI 1.8.11
JqGrid 3.8.2

Here are my includes in the HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/default/scripts/jquery/jqGrid/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/default/scripts/jquery/jqGrid/jquery.jqGrid.3.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

All of these script links are working correctly.
Here is my Grid definition:

```
$('#adminPermissionsGrid').jqGrid({
    url:'/admin/permission/get-permissions',
    mtype: 'GET',
    datatype: 'json',
    jsonReader: {
        id: 'id',
        repeatitems: false
    },
    colModel: adminPermissionsColumnModel,
    pager: '#adminPermissionsPager',
    rowNum: 50,
    altRows: true,
    hidegrid: false,
    sortname: 'resource',
    autowidth: true,
    height: 450,
    gridview: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: translate.admin_table_permission_caption,
    onSelectRow: function(rowId, status) {
        populatePermissionForm(rowId);
    }
})
.navGrid('#adminPermissionsPager',{add:false, edit:false, del:false, search:false, refresh:true});
```

And here is "populatePermissionForm()"

```
function populatePermissionForm(rowId)
{
    //TODO : WTF? Why can't I use jqgrid functions here?
    var rowData = $('#adminPermissionsGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);
    ...
}
```

So here is my problem. I load the grid with $(document).ready(). The grid works as expected, has about 20 rows of data in it. When I click on one of the rows I get the following error in firebug:

```
$("#adminPermissionsGrid").jqGrid is not a function
```

It reports that this line is the culprit:

var rowData = $('#adminPermissionsGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', rowId);

I've inspected $("#adminPermissionsGrid") with Firebug and it still looks as if the grid object is attached to it. I've spent hours trying to find the answer to this. It seems that after the initial load, I can't use any grid methods. I have a HACKY workaround that surfs the DOM of the grid, but I don't want to do that...

Any thoughts?

Comment: My psychic powers tell me that the `$()` function changes between your first call to `jqGrid()` and the call to `populatePermissionForm()`. Are you using other frameworks in the page besides jQuery?

Comment: You can try to include the code of `populatePermissionForm` directly inside of `onSelectRow` and see whether you have the same problem. You can additionally try make the demo which can be used to reproduce your problem. If you additionally post the test JSON response from the server (you can catch the data with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)), that one could use the demo without having any server components.

Comment: Tried including the code of populatePermissionForm inside of onSelectRow and that didn't work. @frederic-hamidi you're psychic powers were correct, if I change it to jQuery from $ it works. However, I'm not using any other frameworks. So I'll have to figure that out... but thanks for getting me started down the right path.

Comment: Your explanation means that your code overwrite `$` or at least some methods of `$`. You can start the example in the debugger (Developer Tools of IE or Chrome or Firebug are enough) and examine the global `$` object. In the way it should be possible to localize where you do the changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Culprit found! I'm using the ZFDebug plugin for Zend which relies on jQuery. This plugin automatically turns on noConflict. There is not option in the plugin to toggle this, but when I comment out the noConflict line... everything works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I've got the same problem with *jQgrid* and *ZfDebug* using the *`noConflict`* method.

ZfDebug toolbar script is loaded first of all, then it first look for jQuery... no chance to find it because it's himself the first in line ! So it gets an old version of jQuery from google api's and the problems start.

You can send to ZfDebug, as an option, a path to the version of jQuery you want, locally or not. In your application.ini put:

```
zfdebug.jquery_path = "/my_path_to_jquery/jquery-xxx.min.js"
```

(or as a member of an options array in your bootstrap if you prefer).